# I want to implement this functionality <input type="number" /> with inputNumber from antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I want to implement this functionality  with inputNumber from antd, I would like keep the value written in the input, but antd always modify the number **should not allow to type letter, and many times comma or dot**

i want this behavior

```html
<input type="number" />
```

this is the code:

```
export const parserNumber = (val) => {
  if (!val) return 0;
  return Number.parseFloat(val.replace(/\$\s?|(\.*)/g, "").replace(/(\,{1})/g, ".")).toFixed(2)
}

<Input
  parser={(value) => parserNumber(value)}
/>
```

when i typed 3,5 the value is changing to 3

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with `antd` but the issue you're seeing could be due to the parsing of the number, where when you use a `,` the number is interpreted is such a way that the max is reached.

Given the clarification in the comment, I don't think you can really do that in one property. You'll have to store an actual value (value independent of the way it was entered, and restricted to interpreting decimals as both a dot and comma) and a display value (storing the value as entered).

```
const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(3);

  const formatValue = (value) => {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      /* Replace commas with dots */
      return value.replace(/,/g, '.');
    }
    return value;
  };

  const parseValue = (value) => {
    /* Replace dots with commas */
    return String(value).replace(/\./g, ',');
  };

  const onChange = (newValue) => {
    const parsedValue = parseValue(newValue);
    setValue(parsedValue);
  };

  return (
    <InputNumber
      (...)
      onChange={onChange}
      formatter={formatValue}
      parser={parseValue}
    />
  );
};
```

This is a pretty loose example, there's probably a better way to do this that better fits your use case.

Comment: but i dont want to replace, only i want to keep the value that i written

Comment: updated - give the comment about storing an actual value and a display value as separate a consideration

Comment: only i want to show in the input, dont deleting commas or dots, it should keep the number written

Comment: sure, from reading the docs for andt it's literally not possible out of the box. Numbers are parsed in a standardized way...no amount of your desire can change that. If you want to change the convention you have to write your own logic. The code provided is meant to illustrate the idea, not actually solve your issues fully.

Answer (score 0):

you can custom Input using onchange

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
const [value, setValue] = useState('');

const handleInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
const inputValue = e.target.value;

const cleanedValue = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9.,]/g, '');

setValue(cleanedValue);
};
return <Input value={value} onChange={handleInputChange} />;
};
```